# VS for Mac .tsx code highlighter issue

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I just open a react SPA template built with dotnet new but the code highlighter for .tsx in VS for mac is so mess up the code is not readable. Any suggestion for fixing it?

Comment: VS for Mac has a feedback item under its menu, so write down what you think of and let Microsoft know.